# Unable to capture screenshot of a local webpage

Tags: javascript, css, html

> This problem is related to: [Capture the screenshot of a webpage using html2canvas with png extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21315051/capture-the-screenshot-of-a-webpage-using-html2canvas-with-png-extension)

Hi!

This is my first post here, so I apologize in advance for any mistake I may make here. I am trying to build a drag and drop timetable which the volunteers will have to submit to authority. The timetable must have an option of saving it in jpg format. This is the program I am using but when I click on "Save" button, a new page opens with "data:;" as address

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!--<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">-->
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>NSS BITS PILANI</title>
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src ="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="html2canvas.js?rev032"></script> 
    <!--<script src="~/Js/html2canvas.js"></script>-->
    <!--<script src="~/Js/jquery.plugin.html2canvas.js"></script>-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(window).load(function(){

        $('#load').click(function(){

                html2canvas($('#testdiv'), {
                    onrendered: function (canvas) {
                        var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
                        window.location.href = img;
                    }
                });

        });
});

</script>       

<body>

    <img src = "http://s20.postimg.org/art5c3vot/NSS.gif" alt = "NSS BITS Pilani - Pilani Campus">
    <h2>Share your timetable</h2>
    <div class="info" style="margin-bottom:10px">
        <div>Click and drag the correct status of the hour to timetable.</div>

    <div style="width:700px;">
        <div class="left">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><div class="item">Free</div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><div class="item">Busy</div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><div class="item">Lunch</div></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div id = "testdiv">
        <div class="right">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td class="blank"></td>
                    <td class="title">Monday</td>
                    <td class="title">Tuesday</td>
                    <td class="title">Wednesday</td>
                    <td class="title">Thursday</td>
                    <td class="title">Friday</td>
                    <td class="title">Saturday</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="time">08:00</td>
                    <td class="drop"></td>
                    <td class="drop"></td>
                    <td class="drop"></td>
                    <td class="drop"></td>
                    <td class="drop"></td>
                    <td class="drop"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="time">09:00</td>
                    <td class="drop"></td>
                    <td class="drop"></td>
                    <td class="drop"></td>
                    <td class="drop"></td>
                    <td class="drop"></td>
                    <td class="drop"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="time">10:00</td>
                    <td class="drop"></td>
                    <td class="drop"></td>
                    <td class="drop"></td>
                    <td class="drop"></td>
                    <td class="drop"></td>
                    <td class="drop"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="time">11:00</td>
                    <td class="drop"></td>
                    <td class="drop"></td>
                    <td class="drop"></td>
                    <td class="drop"></td>
                    <td class="drop"></td>
                    <td class="drop"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="time">12:00</td>
                    <td class="drop"></td>
                    <td class="drop"></td>
                    <td class="drop"></td>
                    <td class="drop"></td>
                    <td class="drop"></td>
                    <td class="drop"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="time">1:00</td>
                    <td class="drop"></td>
                    <td class="drop"></td>
                    <td class="drop"></td>
                    <td class="drop"></td>
                    <td class="drop"></td>
                    <td class="drop"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="time">2:00</td>
                    <td class="drop"></td>
                    <td class="drop"></td>
                    <td class="drop"></td>
                    <td class="drop"></td>
                    <td class="drop"></td>
                    <td class="drop"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="time">3:00</td>
                    <td class="drop"></td>
                    <td class="drop"></td>
                    <td class="drop"></td>
                    <td class="drop"></td>
                    <td class="drop"></td>
                    <td class="drop"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="time">4:00</td>
                    <td class="drop"></td>
                    <td class="drop"></td>
                    <td class="drop"></td>
                    <td class="drop"></td>
                    <td class="drop"></td>
                    <td class="drop"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="time">5:00</td>
                    <td class="drop"></td>
                    <td class="drop"></td>
                    <td class="drop"></td>
                    <td class="drop"></td>
                    <td class="drop"></td>
                    <td class="drop"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="time">6:00</td>
                    <td class="drop"></td>
                    <td class="drop"></td>
                    <td class="drop"></td>
                    <td class="drop"></td>
                    <td class="drop"></td>
                    <td class="drop"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="button" value="Save" id="load"/>
    </div>
    </div>
    <style type="text/css">
        .left{
            width:120px;
            float:left;
        }
        .left table{
            background:#E0ECFF;
        }
        .left td{
            background:#eee;
        }
        .right{
            float:right;
            width:570px;
        }
        .right table{
            background:#E0ECFF;
            width:100%;
        }
        .right td{
            background:#fafafa;
            color:#444;
            text-align:center;
            padding:2px;
        }
        .right td{
            background:#E0ECFF;
        }
        .right td.drop{
            background:#fafafa;
            width:100px;
        }
        .right td.over{
            background:#FBEC88;
        }
        .item{
            text-align:center;
            border:1px solid #499B33;
            background:#fafafa;
            color:#444;
            width:100px;
        }
        .assigned{
            border:1px solid #BC2A4D;
        }
        .trash{
            background-color:red;
        }

    </style>
    <script>

        $(function(){
            $('.left .item').draggable({
                revert:true,
                proxy:'clone'
            });
            $('.right td.drop').droppable({
                onDragEnter:function(){
                    $(this).addClass('over');
                },
                onDragLeave:function(){
                    $(this).removeClass('over');
                },
                onDrop:function(e,source){
                    $(this).removeClass('over');
                    if ($(source).hasClass('assigned')){
                        $(this).append(source);
                    } else {
                        var c = $(source).clone().addClass('assigned');
                        $(this).empty().append(c);
                        c.draggable({
                            revert:true
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
            $('.left').droppable({
                accept:'.assigned',
                onDragEnter:function(e,source){
                    $(source).addClass('trash');
                },
                onDragLeave:function(e,source){
                    $(source).removeClass('trash');
                },
                onDrop:function(e,source){
                    $(source).remove();
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Can someone please point out the reason for this strange behavior?

Thanks

**Edit**: If I comment out the css style part, then the webpage is working perfectly... Is their a way to include that CSS Styling in the screenshot as well?

Comment: can you make fiddle for this ? [ http://jsfiddle.net/ ]

Comment: @Jen, I will try.. This is the first time for me, so, it may take some time :)

Comment: @Jen, here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/evv5zzb8/
I couldn't type <script type = "text/javascript"> etc. thing in head as it was allowing me to do that...

Comment: i had look on your code. You have not include any external resource that has been used in your code.

Comment: In the fiddle you mean? Yeah, I couldn't include the <script src... > thing in head in the HTML section... It's showing an error for that.

Comment: just remove your <script> tag and add code in javascript section. And add external file used in external resources section.

Comment: @Jen, thanks for the help :) I have updated the fiddle

Comment: May there is something wrong because your fiddle is not opening.

Comment: @Jen, I will try something else in that case :) Thanks for your help